# Save attachment from Gmail to Google Drive AND give it another name by appending the time stamp of the email

Tags: timestamp, gmail, attachment, gdrive

We are using the google apps script to download the files to Gdrive successfully using the URL https://github.com/ahochsteger/gmail2gdrive

Is it possible to download the file to Gdrive by appending the timestamp to the downloaded files?

If so, How can we do it using the code in the URL https://github.com/ahochsteger/gmail2gdrive?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, The code is present here https://github.com/ahochsteger/gmail2gdrive.